# Do i need to unsubscribe from a Promise that has been converted to an Observable with Observable.from()?

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable

I know you don't have to unsubscribe from a promise, but what if i use the `from()` rxjs operator to turn that promise into a observable and subscribe to it like so:

```
    from(image.decode()).pipe(catchError(error => of('failed to load image')))
    .subscribe(s => this.imageLoading = false)
```

I've looked in the official documentation for `from()` and on different tutorial sites but none of them mention anything about unsubscribing. Can anyone please clarify? Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you have `from(promise)`, I'd say you **don't have to unsubscribe**.

[Here's](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/src/internal/observable/from.ts#L109-L118) how `from` is defined:

```js
export function from<T>(input: ObservableInput<T>, scheduler?: SchedulerLike): Observable<T> {
  if (!scheduler) {
    if (input instanceof Observable) {
      return input;
    }
    
    // Reached when having `from(promise)`
    return new Observable<T>(subscribeTo(input));
  } else {
    return scheduled(input, scheduler);
  }
}
```

[`subscribeTo`](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/ea8ef13ed7f8c8ae8b8882f6b105fcd027b7d217/src/internal/util/subscribeTo.ts#L15) is defined as follows:

```js
/* ... */
else if (isPromise(result)) {
  return subscribeToPromise(result);
}
/* ... */
```

And finally, [`subscribeToPromise`](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/ea8ef13ed7f8c8ae8b8882f6b105fcd027b7d217/src/internal/util/subscribeToPromise.ts#L4):

```js
export const subscribeToPromise = <T>(promise: PromiseLike<T>) => (subscriber: Subscriber<T>) => {
  promise.then(
    (value) => {
      if (!subscriber.closed) {
        subscriber.next(value);
        subscriber.complete();
      }
    },
    (err: any) => subscriber.error(err)
  )
  .then(null, hostReportError);
  return subscriber;
};
```

As you can see, after the first emitted value, it will send a `complete` notification, so there is no need to unsubscribe.

[StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-from-promise-unsub?file=index.ts).